# Call static method from another class without creating object in Java

Tags: java, class, oop, methods, static

Can we access a static method defined in one class inside another class without creating an object of the class in which the static method is defined?

```
class Test{
      public static int add(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }

}

public class Methods{
  
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("The sum of 2 and 3 is: " + add(2,3));

    }
}
```

In this code snippet, when I try to call the `add` method defined in the `Test` class from the `Methods` class, I get the following error:

```
Methods.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("The sum of 2 and 3 is: " + add(2,3));
                                                       ^
  symbol:   method add(int,int)
  location: class Methods
1 error
```

But when I try to call the static method using the object of the `Test` method inside `Methods`, it works fine!

Comment: `Test.add(2,3)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "using the object of the Test method"?

Comment: I think he means something like this abomination: `new Test().add(2, 3);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
add(2,3)
```

Do

```
Test.add(2,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of creating a static method is accessing it without creating an instance of the class. However the class name needs to be referenced, since you are defining the method in it. So in your case, you need to Test.add(a,b), where Test is the name of the class and not an instance of it.